# Javascript client side validation with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

Below is some javascript validation I have on a simple form.  The first time I hit submit the validation will work and fire and error messages.  If I get an error, enter in new values that are still incorrect and hit submit again the validation does not work anymore and the values are passed to my php form.

Here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
<!--
function validateMyForm ( ) { 
    var isValid = true;
    if ( document.form1.gamedate.value === "Select One" ) { 
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = ( "Please select a game" ); 
            isValid = false;
    } else if ( document.form1.wteam.value === "Select One" ) { 
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = ( "Please select the winning team" ); 
            isValid = false;
    } else if ( document.form1.wscore.value === "Select One" ) { 
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = ( "Please select the winning score" ); 
            isValid = false;
    } else if ( document.form1.lscore.value === "Select One" ) {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = ( "Please select the losing score");
            isValid = false;
    } else if ( document.form1.wscore.value <= document.form1.lscore.value ){
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = ( "Winning score must be larger than the losing score");
            isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
//-->
</script>
```

php form with ******* to remove certain data

```
<form action="*********" method="post" name="form1">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Game Date:</label>
           <select name="gamedate">
               <option>Select One</option>
               <?php
               $stmt = $db->prepare("***********)");
               $stmt->execute(array(':**********' => $_SESSION['**********']));
                 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                 echo '<option value="';
                 echo $row['*********'];
                 echo '">';
                 echo $row['*********'];
                 echo '</option>';
                 }
               ?>
           </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Winning Team</label>
           <select name="wteam">
               <option>Select One</option>
               <option value="1">Home</option>
               <option value="0">Opponent</option>
           </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Winning Score</label>
            <select name="wscore">
                <option>Select One</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>          
            </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Losing Score</label>
            <select name="lscore">
                <option>Select One</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>  
            </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:return validateMyForm();">      
</form>
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `javascript:` from the `onclick`. `onclick` already triggers javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript validation is great however you should also be doing the same validation steps in your PHP form handler.  Then if it does not pass validation from the PHP form handler, you redirect back to the page with your form again.  Preferrably pre-filling the valid fields and noting which fields need to be corrected.

Javascript validation should be considered an ADD-ON to server side validation.

@danl Here is some basic PHP validation.  I'm not certain what format your gamedate variable should be to check it.  The others are very basic.

```
$haserror=false;

$gamedate=$_POST['gamedate'];
//not sure what is valid for gamedate.  But you should check it against something
if(strlen($gamedate)<1){
    $haserror=true;
    $errordetail.=' Game Date must be selected';
}

$wteam=$_POST['wteam'];
if(!(($wteam==1) || ($wteam==0))){
    $haserror=true;
    $errordetail.=' Winning team must be selected';
}

$wscore=$_POST['wscore'];
if(!is_numeric($wscore)){
    $haserror=true;
    $errordetail.=' Winning score does not appear to be a valid number';
}
$lscore=$_POST['lscore'];
if(!is_numeric($lscore)){
    $haserror=true;
    $errordetail.=' Losing score does not appear to be a valid number';
}

if($lscore > $wscore){
    $haserror=true;
    $errordetail.=' Losing score should not be more than the winning score.';
}

if($haserror){
   echo $errordetail;
   exit();
}
else{
   echo'  Success! .  Process the data here';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I am very new to code and have looked into PHP validation but it has all gone WAY over my head.  Looking at the code above is there a simple way to validate that Select One is not entered and that wscore is greater than lscore with PHP?

Comment: added the php validation and I have not been able to break it at all!  thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Your validate function is being called from the wrong place.  It should be called from the form's `onsubmit` method, not the submit button's `onclick` method:

```
<form action="*********" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="return validateMyForm()">
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I updated the location of the onsubmit and tested and it still is allowing me to enter errant data, but it is now taking more clicks and updates to finally accept it so we are moving in the right direction at least :-)

Comment: @danl, Maybe it has to do with you using `===` rather than just `==`. Try using just `==` and see what happens.

Comment: Still is not working correctly with == instead of ===.  I am starting to wonder if somehow I have to totally clear out a variable each time the error message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to grab the value of the drop-down in your javascript, but then you're comparing it against the text of the drop-down. Either assign values to the default drop-down options and compare against those, or change your javascript to grab the text (e.g. "Select One") instead.

Comment: I thought this worked as it I was not getting errors no matter how much I tried until I submitted the form correctly and then went back to the form page to enter in another selection and I am yet again able to submit errant data. :-(

Comment: Comment out the contents of ValidateMyForm() and just have it always return false. Is it possible to submit errant data then? If not, start uncommenting and testing each validator individually. Add an alert to display the submitted data at the top of the function so you can make sure you're pulling data correctly and that your comparisons are accurate for each step in the validation.